# Select from a certain row and onwards with mysql

Tags: mysql, select

How can I select from a certain row and onwards?

For instance, the table I want to query,

```
pg_id   pg_title    pg_backdate
1       a           2012-09-18 13:32:49
2       b           2011-09-18 13:32:49
3       c           2011-06-18 13:32:49
4       d           2010-05-18 13:32:49
5       e           2009-04-18 13:32:49
6       f           2011-10-18 13:32:49
7       g           2012-04-18 13:32:49
8       h           2012-09-18 13:32:49
9       i           2012-10-18 13:32:49
```

I want to select the top 5 rows only, starting from current month and year and onwards, I have worked on the query below - it only selects the top 5 of current month and current year but not the rows onwards,

```
SELECT *
    FROM root_pages AS p

    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(p.pg_backdate, '%Y') = '2011'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(p.pg_backdate, '%m') = '09' 

    ORDER BY p.pg_backdate DESC

    LIMIT 5
```

Ideally, it should return these rows only,

```
pg_id   pg_title    pg_backdate
1       a           2012-09-18 13:32:49
2       b           2011-09-18 13:32:49
6       f           2011-10-18 13:32:49
7       g           2012-04-18 13:32:49
8       h           2012-09-18 13:32:49
```

Comment: You probably want the the results sorted ascending, right?

Comment: yes it is to be ascending. thanks Salman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM root_pages
WHERE pg_backdate >= '2011-09-01'
ORDER BY pg_backdate
LIMIT 0, 5
```

The above query will return 5 rows starting from 1st day of September 2011 and onwards. An `ORDER BY` clause will return the dates closest to that date. You can generate the date (1st of current month) via PHP - or - you can have MySQL do that for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM root_pages
WHERE pg_backdate >= CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 1) AS DATE)
ORDER BY pg_backdate
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: thanks for this. I like this answer as it is easier and I dont have to use PHP to generate the date. can I ask - CAST, CONCAT_WS - what do they mean? thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You can look them up in the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html). In summary, `CAST` converts one datatype to another (varchar to date in this case); `CONCAT_WS` is CONCATenate With Separator, concatenates current year, current month and 1 using `-` as the glue.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM root_pages AS p
WHERE p.pg_backdate >= '2011-09-01'
ORDER BY p.pg_backdate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Using functions like you do will kill any chance MySQL has of using an index.

If you want to select the top 5 from the month do:

```
SELECT *
FROM root_pages AS p
WHERE p.pg_backdate BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2011-09-30'
ORDER BY p.pg_backdate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

If you want the top 5 in the month **and** the rows beyond, then do

```
  SELECT *
  FROM root_pages AS p
  WHERE p.pg_backdate BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2011-09-30'
  ORDER BY p.pg_backdate DESC
  LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM root_pages AS p
  WHERE p.pg_backdate > '2011-09-30'
  ORDER BY p.pg_backdate DESC
```

Comment: Usually newer stuff comes first, who cares about old stuff... right. But if if want it visa versa, just remove the `DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

He wants to order by id it seems...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM root_pages AS p
WHERE p.pg_backdate >=  '2011-09-01'
ORDER BY p.pg_backdate DESC 
LIMIT 5
) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.pg_id
```